# Stacktrace for angularjs ?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, stack-trace, error-logging

Need some expert advice for client side error handling....

I have a angularjs web application using C# at the backend. I am using Nlog to log backend errors to the database.

I want to find out which tool can be used for logging client side errors to the database. I googled a bit and found various tools like TRACKJS, ROLLBAR..... and these are for javascript error logging...

I found one for angular. STACKTRACE.JS.... i wanted to know what difference will it make if i use TRACKJS instead of STACKTRACE in angular. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacktrace.js allows you to better debug JavaScript in your own browser, as you develop. Tools like Track.js (and Sentry) are more for production, where errors that your users are experiencing are logged to a server. From there, they are aggregated and you can view reports/get alerts.

(disclaimer, I'm an engineer at Sentry, which has a [1-line Angular integration](https://getsentry.com/for/angular/). We're also uniquely [100% BSD licensed open source](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry), if you prefer running your own servers.)

Comment: @ehfeng- you mentioned that stacktrace.js is useful more when developing. does it not work well at production ?  can you share a link which shows track.js or sentry is more powerful than stacktrace.js.. any comments on the differences or advantages is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: stacktrace.js doesn't given you a server/reporting, just gives you a consistent stacktrace across browsers.
Tools like Sentry give you more of a workflow tool for dealing with production errors. We do javascript source maps decompression automatically, wrap native functions, etc. You can learn a bit about it on posts like these: https://blog.getsentry.com/2016/02/03/wrap-javascript-functions.html

Comment: i didnt get wat you meant ? does it mean that stacktrace doesnt allow to report the error msgs to the databasE ?

Comment: You can report error msgs to a server/database, but you'd like to write it yourself.

Comment: you mean to say track.js and sentry has the web api which does all these for us ?

Comment: Yes. Sentry has an open source and a hosted service. Track.js offers a propriety hosted service.

You can also track your C# errors with Sentry.